# Going to a virtual terminal disables Vim color scheme

Tags: gnome, vim, console

When I'm going into a virtual terminal my Vim color scheme is ignored.

I've configured it by following [this blog](http://codissimo.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/enhancing-vim-as-an-htmljscssphp-editor/).

Heres all of my `~/.vimrc`

```
if $COLORTERM == 'gnome-terminal'
    set term=gnome-256color
    set t_Co=256
    colorscheme railscasts
else
    colorscheme default
endif


"FileType support
set filetype=on
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on

"Color scheme and font
autocmd FileType javascript,html,css,php colorscheme railscasts
autocmd FileType javascript,html,css,php set gfn=Monaco\ 10

"Indentation
autocmd FileType javascript,html,css,php set ai
autocmd FileType javascript,html,css,php set sw=4
autocmd FileType javascript,html,css,php set ts=4
autocmd FileType javascript,html,css,php set sts=4
autocmd FileType javascript,css,php set textwidth=79

"Enable autocompletion
autocmd FileType javascript set omnifunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS
autocmd FileType html set omnifunc=htmlcomplete#CompleteTags
autocmd FileType css set omnifunc=csscomplete#CompleteCSS

"Enable line numbers
autocmd FileType javascript,css,php set number

"Enable incremental search
autocmd FileType javascript,html,css,php set incsearch
```

This part should have been fixed it right?

```
if $COLORTERM == 'gnome-terminal'
    set term=gnome-256color
    set t_Co=256
    colorscheme railscasts
else
    colorscheme default
endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done but it quite complicated (so I recommend using a regular terminal if you really want the colors) but if you really want to do it have a look at the following question on superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/67582/tty-with-256-colors

They instruct to set the appropriate TERM variable, this TERM variable then also needs to be added to your vimrc, becaues now the colors are only set for `TERM=gnome-terminal`.

Comment: What's up with these 256 limitations? Can't I just have 32bit or 64bit color???? I mean, dude, it's 2013, why aren't all terminals 32bit colored by now?!